# How can I get the list of all tables used in all the stored procedures of a particular schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'd like to find all the tables used in all the stored procedures of a particular schema. I've tried to use the following code for checking the tables used in one Stored Procedure, however, I received an empty table though there are many tables used in the stored procedure.

```
SELECT SD.DEPID   
FROM SYSOBJECTS SO,   
     SYSDEPENDS SD  
WHERE SO.NAME = '<name of stored procedure>
  AND SD.ID = SO.ID
```

I'm new to SSMS and SQL. Hope you can help. Thank you!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not to use sysdepends table, as it is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. [Sysdepends on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysdepends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> This SQL Server 2000 system table is included as a view for backward
> compatibility. We recommend that you use the current SQL Server system
> views instead. To find the equivalent system view or views, see
> Mapping System Tables to System Views (Transact-SQL). This feature
> will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid
> using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify
> applications that currently use this feature.

You can use sql_expression_dependencies to get that.

[More Information on SQL_Expression_Dependencies usage scenarios](https://database.guide/find-dependencies-in-sql-server-sql_expression_dependencies/)

The advantage of expression dependencies is that, it can also tell CROSS DATABASE dependencies

```sql
SELECT
    referenced_server_name AS [Referenced Server],
    referenced_database_name AS [Referenced DB],
    referenced_schema_name AS [Referenced Schema],
    referenced_entity_name AS [Referenced Entity],
    referenced_class_desc AS [Referenced Entity Class] 
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies as ep
INNER JOIN sys.procedures as p
on ep.referencing_id = p.object_id -- Referencing Stored Procedure Object Id
where p.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo') -- dbo schema
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created few tables, procedure and after that wrote(copy - paste) a query and all by following the article I have found on internet: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/find-list-of-tables-used-in-stored-procedure-using-types-of-joins

Here is the query that will get you the list of tables:

```
SELECT   
NAME as 'List Of Tables'  
FROM SYSOBJECTS  
WHERE ID IN (   SELECT SD.DEPID   
                FROM SYSOBJECTS SO  
                join SYSDEPENDS SD  on SD.ID = SO.ID
            )
```

And here is the demo :

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9446e040d35154f8e9b8ee6ac093f52)